# I want to show error message when textbox is null in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I am new in ASP.Net MVC 4. I have one textbox and one button. I want to show the error message when textbox is null after clicking on the button.

can anyone help me.
My Account class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Security;
namespace WebApplication6.Models
{
    public class Account
    {
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name {0}")]
        [StringLength(5)]
       public string Name { get; set; }



      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Family {0}")]
      public string Family { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Layout page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="~/Content/CSS/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/Logo.jpg" style="position:center; border-top-color:red;" />
        </div>
    </header>
    <div>
        <h1 class="header">Wellcome to company's project</h1>

    </div>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
   <footer>
       @Html.Partial("_Footer")
   </footer>
</body
```

>

My controller is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication6.Models;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Login/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginResult()
        {
            Account Oaccount = new Account();
           Oaccount.Name = Request.Form["name"];
           Oaccount.Family = Request.Form["family"];

             /*if (Oaccount.Name=="" || Oaccount.Family=="")
            {
             return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('You must enter both fields');</script>");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            } 
            else {*/
           string Fullname=string.Format("{0} {1}", Oaccount.Name,Oaccount.Family);

                ViewBag.Message = Fullname;

            return View("Result");
        }
```

My Index View is:

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.Account 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "LoginResult", controllerName: "Login"))
{
    <fieldset >
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <p class="textbox">
            Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Name)
        </p>
        <p >
            Family: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Family)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Family)
        </p>
        <p class="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}

        }
    }
```

And my Result view is:

```
@using WebApplication6.Models
@model WebApplication6.Models.Account
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Result";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}

<h2>Result</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Login Result</legend>
    <p>

        Wellcome
        @ViewBag.Message


    </p>
</fieldset>>
```

Comment: How do you render that textbox? Are you using HtmlHelper extensions?

Comment: I use html.beginform and html.textboxfor

Comment: Is there any reason you do not use client side validation (so you get client and server side validation out of the box)? Other wise you will nee javascript to handle the buttons `.click()` event, check the value and display a message.

Comment: Your have not included `jquery-{version}.js` (needs to be the first script in the layout). You submit to `LoginResult()` but that method does not even have a parameter - needs to be `LoginResult(Account model)`. These are only 2 of multiple errors in your code. I strongly suggest you go to the MVC site and work through some basic tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You can do validation in mvc either by using javascript which is not recommended as mvc provides built in Client-Server validation. Just create a model class with column name like this and provide Required Data Annotation

```
public class Your_Class_Name
{
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {0}")]
        public string Column_Name{ get; set; }
}
```

and add this script file to your project.
   //Download this 2 jquery file and add it in your Layout view

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Later create a Strongly type View with this class model.

It is very important to use Validationmessage html helper if you want to show error message. In your view after your textbox add this line 
Ex:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Column_Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Column_Name)
```

I am not getting what's the problem, mean while change your controller action method and check for modelstate like: [HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult LoginResult(Account objAccount)
    { 
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
                 Account Oaccount = new Account();
                 Oaccount.Name = objAccount.Name ;
                 Oaccount.Family = objAccount.Family ;

                 //Rest of the code
          }
     }
```

see what modelstate.isvalid returns

Comment: I add this code in my Account class: [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter {0}")]
      public string Family { get; set; }

Comment: I add this two Javascripts in my layout page <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script> 
and these two files were downloaded and added to Scripts file. And also @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Family)  was added to my view. But it doesnt work.

Comment: can you post your model class, controller action method and view, so that i can go through

Comment: In your  Index View you have called Begin form but you didn't gave Form method i.e., to do GET or POST. So change it like @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginResult", "Login",FormMethod.Post))

Comment: Add some more jquery files to your layout like <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>  just below to your css stylesheet and see whether its working or not.

Comment: No, it doesnt work. When I click the button the Result view was showed to me. It doesnt matter that the textbox is empty or not.

Comment: I am not getting what's the problem, mean while change your controller action method and check for modelstate like: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginResult(Account objAccount)
        { 
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                     Account Oaccount = new Account();
                     Oaccount.Name = objAccount.Name ;
                     Oaccount.Family = objAccount.Family ;
                     
//Rest of the code
        }} see what modelstate.isvalid returns

Comment: Is it still going to Result view, try to check by keeping breakpoint. If modelstate fails then it means our model is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the field to be not null you can use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Family, new { @required = "required" })
```

If you want more than just not null, add the conditions in like the required condition. or use Rajsh's solution.